# Cannot get JSON from NodeJS API call

Tags: json, node.js, api

I have the following NodeJS piece of code to get JSON structure from exisiting API endpoint:

```
var request = require('request');

request({
    url: 'http://192.168.56.101:8088/json/disc/bases'
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
});
```

When I `console.log(body)` I get something empty while if I open the URL directly into a tab of my browser, I clearly get an answer, a non-prettified json object.

If I try with the API http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 for instance, I don't have any struggle, the `console.log(body)` returns the expected json. Although, I have noticed many differences in the header responses: while the jsonplaceholder API returns 14 elements in its header :

[image]

My API returns only 3 elements :

[image]

Do you guys have any idea of what that means and what I can do to get the JSON. I looked into many other way to do so but nothing is helping. I hope you can get me out of the devil issue I am getting tired off. Thank you !

Comment: Your code works just fine. I think your API is not returning a valid JSON. Three steps: 1/ try with an url from http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ to validate your code, 2/ try your original url without `json: true` (you should get something in the console), 3/ validate the output JSON: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried that, it works with jsonplaceholder, and with my API now, I got it to send a non-empty array, so the browser clearly returns something when calling directly, but when I `console.log(body)`, I get an empty line in my console, like the content is juste " ".

What's that `[Circular]` thing in the all output?

Comment: The `[Circular]` is here with both requests. So that's not the issue. The only difference I see when calling both APIs directly into the browser, is the pretty print. And the json of my API is said valid by jsonlint.com

Comment: Don't bother with the Circular thing, it means `response` is a very complex object and has [circular reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) (it has properties referencing itself). Did you try without `json: true`?

Comment: Did you inspect response body in plain old http.get/curl?

Comment: Can you post more code from the file that is making the request (especially where you create the url variable).  Form what I've done you do not pass three parameters to the callback.  You may be able to just use `consoe.log(response.body)` to print out the value.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I updated my original answer with the exact piece of code I am trying to run. I tried calling the API with curl and I get the exepcted response. Runing the same get request with the code shown just returns something empty, and `undefined` if I set `json:true`. I guess the header of the response has something to do with this, but since that is not my API, what could I do? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finding it weird that the response headers have such big differences. So I looked into this direction and also realised the request headers were a lot different when calling the same API from Chrome let's say, and from my NodeJS app.

One of the key:value in the request headers that was different was `Connection: keep-alive`. I therefore added this header to the request in my NodeJS app, and things work has expected now. Thank you for your help.

Here the final code:

```
var request = require('request');

request({
    url: 'http://192.168.56.101:8088/json/disc/bases',
    headers: {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    }
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
});
```